# What is the best way to structure Python projects using a shared package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project, python-import

I am currently developing a package simultaneously with a few projects that use the package, and I'm struggling to figure out how to structure my directory tree and imports.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
main_directory
├── shared_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── package_file1.py
│   └── package_file2.py
├── project1
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── other_package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── other_package_file.py
└── project2
    └── ...
```

I can't figure out how to make the imports work cleanly for importing `shared_package` from python files in project1. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_package` will eventually be standalone. Other people will import and install it the normal way, and it'll be stored with the rest of the python modules in `site-packages` or wherever.

To replicate this, I recommend just updating your `PYTHONPATH` to point to `main_directory` (or wherever you put `shared_package` anyway) - that way,

```
import shared_package
```

will still work fine for the code if `shared_package` was installed normally, because it's on the pythonpath either way.

Note that `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable, so the means for doing this will vary based on your operating system. Regardless, a quick search for how to modify the variable permanently on your OS should be easy.